# PHP Server Error 500 when Echo doesnt exist?

Tags: php, echo

My php code works fine when I add in an echo in a certain spot, but when I remove the simple `echo "hello";` line it doesnt load the php page and it just shows Server Error 500.

The following code works:

```
require 'steam.php';
    $steam = new steam();
    $api = "FC1D74A835829EB99A571235A499638A";
    $query = 'ari9';

    $communityID            =   $steam->getID($query, $api);
    $userInfo               =   $steam->getUserInfo($communityID, $api);

    echo "hello";

    $info = array(
        'communityID'   =>  $communityID,
        'steamID'       =>  $steam->$convertToSteamID($communityID),
        'personaname'   =>  $userInfo['personaname'],
        'profileurl'    =>  $userInfo['profileurl'],
        'lastlogoff'    =>  $userInfo['lastlogoff'],
    );

    foreach ($info as $key => $value) {
        if (strlen($value)===0) {
            $info[$key] = false;
        }
        echo $key." -> ".$value."<br>";
    }
    echo json_encode($info);
```

And the following code does **not** work:

```
require 'steam.php';
    $steam = new steam();
    $api = "FC1D74A835829EB99A571235A499638A";
    $query = 'ari9';

    $communityID            =   $steam->getID($query, $api);
    $userInfo               =   $steam->getUserInfo($communityID, $api);

    $info = array(
        'communityID'   =>  $communityID,
        'steamID'       =>  $steam->$convertToSteamID($communityID),
        'personaname'   =>  $userInfo['personaname'],
        'profileurl'    =>  $userInfo['profileurl'],
        'lastlogoff'    =>  $userInfo['lastlogoff'],
    );

    foreach ($info as $key => $value) {
        if (strlen($value)===0) {
            $info[$key] = false;
        }
        echo $key." -> ".$value."<br>";
    }
    echo json_encode($info);
```

and the following code does **not** work:

```
require 'steam.php';
    $steam = new steam();
    $api = "FC1D74A835829EB99A571235A499638A";
    $query = 'ari9';

    $communityID            =   $steam->getID($query, $api);
    $userInfo               =   $steam->getUserInfo($communityID, $api);

    $info = array(
        'communityID'   =>  $communityID,
        'steamID'       =>  $steam->$convertToSteamID($communityID),
        'personaname'   =>  $userInfo['personaname'],
        'profileurl'    =>  $userInfo['profileurl'],
        'lastlogoff'    =>  $userInfo['lastlogoff'],
    );

    foreach ($info as $key => $value) {
        if (strlen($value)===0) {
            $info[$key] = false;
        }
        echo $key." -> ".$value."<br>";
    }
    echo json_encode($info);

    echo "Hello";
```

The first piece of code has the echo on line 9 and the second one is identical to the first except the echo on line 9 is removed. I'm puzzled by this.

Comment: Replace **echo "hello";** with **var_dump($userInfo);** to see what is in $userInfo

Comment: I did it and it came up with array(20) { ["steamid"]=> string(17) "76561198132612090"........ }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that this `$steam->$convertToSteamID` is looking for a function with the name of whatever that variables value is. The reason you get the 500 when there isn't an echo is because when you send the echo that serves a 200. There should be events in your log displaying the error. You can't have 2 status codes though on a page.

So just change your function call to:

```
$steam->convertToSteamID
```

and you should be fine.